# Редактор кода

Tags: pascal, html, java, delphi, javascript

Где можно найти программу-редактор для  большинства популярных языков программирования и гипертекстовой разметки: Pascal, Delphi, Java, JavaScript, HTML, VBScript, XML.

Comment: не уверен на счет pascal, delphi но для остального Eclipse вполне подойдет. скорее за все что придется искать и ставить дополнительные plugin'ы для pascal, delphi

Comment: Поиск [Google][1]

  [1]: http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81&pbx=1&oq=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80&aq=1&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=3496l15793l0l18253l20l17l3l0l0l1l903l5264l0.7.2.4.2.1.1l20l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=c9e535dc5339c33b&biw=1280&bih=709&pf=p&pdl=300

Comment: ОС то какая? Знаю, что Windows, просто надо бы указывать по=хорошему.

Comment: ОС Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notepad++
Там много синтаксисов.

Comment: А я сменил Nodepad++ на Geany

Comment: Что же вы все забыли про Sublime Text ?

Comment: Я пробовал Sublime Text и другие из перечисленных, но остановился на Geany

Comment: Фича у Npp в виде разделения окна на два редактора просто офигенна! Пишешь html в одной половине, а CSS в другой половине - профит на лицо!

Comment: +про FunctionList не забываем, господа офицеры. За notepad plus вотирую.

Answer (score 10):

- [SciTE](http://scite.ruteam.ru/)(Scientific TextEditor)
- Far с плагином [Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/farplugin.html)
- Emacs. Хотя если бы вы были никсоидом, вы бы не и задали такой вопрос.

---

UPD.
Чуть не забыл, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) - чудесный редактор с мини-картой ) Легко расширяется на питоне, умеет собирать проекты, проверять правописание и многое другое.

Comment: его даже купить не лень :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [jEdit](http://jedit.org/) - поддерживает более сотни языков

Answer (score 1):

Vim, Emacs, Eclipse

Comment: О_о прямо археолог

Comment: Некромант )

Comment: Лови +1 за Vim

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за вопрос :) в ответах нашел пару интересных вещей.
(просто как то не особо есть необходимость, вот сам и не задумывался).
Сам пользуюсь Programmers Notepad; Notepad++.
Больше первым. Кодим на JavaScript(ExtJs) & PHP.

Answer (score 0):

А также есть отличный веб-редактор [coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/), если вы работаете на OSX.

Answer (score 0):

intelliJ IDEA ultimate почему-то забыли

Comment: Как работает IDEA c Delphi и vbscript?


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/q8uoBw7.jpg

Comment: @fori1ton [1ая же ссылка же][1]


  [1]: http://beta.yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=intelliJ+idea+pascal+plugin&lr=213

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, для каждого дела должен быть свой хороший инструмент. Для HTML, CSS, XML, PHP, SQL, JavaScript лучше **PHPStorm** пока не встречал. Он есть и для GNU/Linux дистрибутивов.